# How to get the title of the Calendar Widget on WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I have a got trouble with getting the title of widgets in the sidebar using WordPress.
As you can see,

[image]

I typed the title of the calendar as "asdasdasd".
Now I want to get the title of the calendar using PHP Code.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I want to get the title of the widget in sidebar. For example, I want to get 'asdasdasd' in sidebar-2.

Comment: Yes I understand. My question is what are you going to do when you retrieve it ? What are you trying to achieve after you get the widget's title ?